# If $f=\chi_{\{0\}}$, how to show $\|f\|_\infty=1$?

Tags: functional-analysis

$(X,\Omega,\mu)$ where $X=[0,1],\Omega=$ Borel subsets of $[0,1]$, and $\mu(S)=\infty$ if $0\in S$, otherwise $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. If $f=\chi_{\{0\}}$, how to show $\|f\|_\infty=1$? Any hint is appreciated.

By definition $\|f\|_\infty=\text{ess sup}_X|f|=\inf\{c\ge0:|f(x)|\le c\text{ a.e.}\}$. I think it is 0.

Comment: If the measure places positive mass at $0$, $||\chi_{\{0\}}||_{\infty}=1$.  Otherwise it's zero.

Comment: Alex, I add some words to the problem. Thanks. @David, I think you are right but I need think more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} \leq 1$, since $|f(x)| \leq 1$ everywhere, and hence a.e.

To show that $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} \geq 1$, we claim that if $|f(x)| \leq c$ a.e., then $c \geq 1$. Suppose not, so that there is some $0 \leq c < 1$ for which $|f(x)| \leq c$ a.e. Then the set for which $|f(x)| \geq 1$ is contained in the set for which $|f(x)| > c$, and hence must have measure zero. But the set for which $|f(x)| \geq 1$ contains $0$, and hence must have infinite measure, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Isaac. It is a very nice proof.